# To write this norm equation better?

Tags: equations, amsmath

I have this norm

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\lVert f \rVert_{L_{2}(\Omega)} = \text{sup}_{
\begin{cases} 
v \in L_{2}(\Omega) \\
v \not= 0
\end{cases}
}
\frac{|(f,v)|} {\lVert v \rVert_{L_{2}(\Omega)}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which looks like

[image]

In the Johnson book about Finite Element methods the regulations are under the suprenum.
However, I am not sure if this is the best way to present this.

**How can you write this equation rigorously?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have many norms in your document, it's better to use `mathtools` for simplifying input. I also add a `\normL` macro defined with the help of `xparse`.

Note that the commands `\abs` and `\norm` (as well as `\normL`) accept an optional argument which can be `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` or `\Bigg` in order to resize the fences; they can also be followed by `*` to imply usage of `\left` and `\right`.

The most important part is, however, `\substack`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\NewDocumentCommand{\normL}{ s O{} m }{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\norm*{#3}}{\norm[#2]{#3}}_{L_2(\Omega)}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\norm{f}_{L_{2}(\Omega)} =
\sup_{\substack{v \in L_{2}(\Omega) \\ v \not= 0}}
  \frac{\abs{(f,v)}}{\norm{v}_{L_{2}(\Omega)}}
\end{equation}
% Simplified notation with \normL
\begin{equation}
\normL{f} =
\sup_{\substack{v \in L_{2}(\Omega) \\ v \not= 0}} \frac{\abs{(f,v)}}{\normL{v}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can not see difference between (1) and (2). Should I change my glasses? lol

Comment: @Sigur The two inputs are indeed supposed to give the same output.

Comment: Ah, great! See them here, with a small xshift to compare: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42709342/q26hp.png

Comment: I love your way of using *DeclarePair*, since it improves the readability of Mathematics inside TeX much.

Comment: Can you give an example how to use this **\absBig{x}**? To make the absolute signs bigger?

Comment: **\Big\abs{x}** not working either. What is the supposed way to integrate this command?

Comment: @masi You're supposed to say `\abs[\Big]{x}`.

Answer (score 12):

First, you should use `\sup`. With `amsmath` you can use `\substack{}` which allows multiple lines on the index.

With `\nolimits` the index is not below the `\sup`.

```
\begin{equation}
\lVert f \rVert_{L_{2}(\Omega)} = \sup\nolimits_{
\substack{v \in L_{2}(\Omega) \\ v \neq 0 } }       %% \neq used
\frac{|(f,v)|}{\lVert v \rVert_{L_{2}(\Omega)}}
\end{equation}
```

The default is below the `\sup`.

```
\begin{equation}
\lVert f \rVert_{L_{2}(\Omega)} = \sup_{
\substack{v \in L_{2}(\Omega) \\ v \neq 0 } }
\frac{|(f,v)|}{\lVert v \rVert_{L_{2}(\Omega)}}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Like @Sigur, I would use `\sup` and a `\substack` directive rather than a `cases` environment to place `v \in L_{2}(\Omega)` and `v \not= 0` immediately below `sup`.

In addition, in order to achieve a slightly better positioning (IMNSHO) of the subscript term `L_2(\Omega)` with respect to the norm terms, I suggest you define a macro called `\norm` that uses explicit `\left` and `\right` directives, as in

```
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert}
```

Note that the *size* of the double vertical bars that encase the `f` and `v` terms won't be affected by the presence of these additional directives. The purpose of using `\left` and `\right`, then, is purely to affect the positioning of the superscript term, which will be lower than if `\left` and `\right` weren't used in conjunction with `\lVert` and `\rVert`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{ \left\lvert#1\right\rvert} % absolute value: single vertical bars
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert} % norm: double vertical bars

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\norm{f}_{L_{2}(\Omega)} = 
\sup_{ \substack{v \in L_{2}(\Omega) \\ v \not= 0} }
\frac{ \abs{(f,v)} }{ \norm{v}_{L_{2}(\Omega)} }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the definition of `\abs` and `\norm` are wrong.

Comment: @egreg - Would you mind elaborating? In the examples at hand, there is *no difference* between the output created by "my" macros and those generated via the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro of the `mathtools` package. Hence, "my" macros can't be that wrong!

Comment: Yes, they are, because they *always* use `\left` and `\right`; you know I'm adamant at this.

Comment: @egreg - I agree with you that the automatic insertion of extra whitespace effected by `\left` and `\right` is, in general, undesirable. However, in the specific case of *absolute-value and norm expressions*, I believe there's actually a (modest) virtue to having LaTeX insert a bit of extra space outside these terms, especially when there are several consecutive such terms: the bit of extra space provides some visual "breathing room" that helps the eye parse the expressions. Give it a try with formulas such as `$k\abs{f}\abs{g}$` and `$a\norm{u}\norm{v}$`...

Comment: No, that's solved by `$a\norm{u}\,\norm{v}$`.

Comment: @egreg - I'm heartened by the fact that your solution (to the problem of typesetting consecutive norm expressions) and mine produce the exact same result. :-)